# Setting background color behind image

Tags: html

I am currently working on a html page. I have a image(logo), that resizes depending on the page size using BootStrap. However, I'd like to change the background color for the images height and 100% width. How can I do this without changing the color of the the whole page?

html

```
<img src="Images\MyImage.jpg" id="bg">
```

css

```
#bg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-height: 199px;
max-width: 350px;
min-height: 20%;
min-width: 20%;

background-color: black;
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: That works. What's the problem? Can you repro?

Comment: Do u wish to color the background or white space in the image?

Comment: I want the background color behind the image to be black. 100% height of the image, and 100% width of the page. I've included a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image inside another class and set the background color for that class.
HTML

```
<div class='something'>
<img src="Images\MyImage.jpg" id="bg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.something{background-color: black;}
```